# TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

from django.db import models

> class Coustomer (models.Model):
> user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
> name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> locality = models.CharField(max_lenght=150)
> zipcode= models.IntegerField()
> state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICES,max_lenght=100)
>
> class Product(models.Model):
> title = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
> selling_price = models.FloatField()
> discount_price = models.FloatField()
> description = models.TextField()
> brand = models.CharField(max_lenght = 100)
> category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICE, max_lenght=2)
> prodect_image = models.ImageField(uploded_to = 'Productimg')
>
> ```
> enter code here
> ```

Comment: try max_length not max_lenght

Answer (score 1):

So you're misspelling `max_length`.

```
class Customer (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=150) zipcode= models.IntegerField() 
    state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICES,max_length=100)
```

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    selling_price = models.FloatField() 
    discount_price = models.FloatField() 
    description = models.TextField() 
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 100) 
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICE, max_length=2) 
    product_image = models.ImageField(uploded_to = 'Productimg')
```